# Trying to find two vector relation

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

This image is from the Problem 15-19 of Introduction to Linear Algebra 3rd Edition by G Strang. I have been trying to find w and v relation. And I find that:

w + (v - u) = 2u = v + w

=> w + v - u = v + w

<=> u = 0 (vector zero)

Am I mistaken somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation in the figure gives
$$
2u = v + w \iff u = (v-u) + w
$$
which can not be the vector to the big dot from the figure, which you used to come up with your initial equation. Some error in that figure, I think.

Update: the lower right vector should be $v$ and not $v-u$, IMHO

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it looks like that I have to pass by those problems. :(

Comment: @ntvy95 Check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453816/mark-the-points-frac34v-frac14w-from-frac12v-frac12w